# How to refactor these if else statements to a function

Tags: php

I have code as following:

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();

// [...] some code

$field_name = 'foo';
if (isset($arr1[$field_name])) {
    $arr1[$field_name]++;
} else {
    $arr1[$field_name] = 1;
}

$another_field_name = 'bar';
if (isset($arr2[$another_field_name])) {
    $arr2[$another_field_name]++;
} else {
    $arr2[$another_field_name] = 1;
}
```

There are many more arrays and the same `ifelse` statements.

I would like to refactor these statements to a function:

```
function ifelse_arr ($arr_name, $field_name) {
    if (isset($arr_name[$field_name])) {
        $arr_name[$field_name]++;
    } else {
        $arr_name[$field_name] = 1;
    }
}
```

But how can I pass an array name and field name as a variable to the function?

Comment: Seems more like you should refactor it to use a loop, and an array of field names.

Comment: Do not pass array name, pass reference to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to pass array nor variable name, you want to pass array and variable themselves.

```
function ppIfIsset(array &$array, $field) {
    $array[$field] = isset($array[$field]) ? $array[$field] + 1 : 1;    
}
```

And call it like

```
ppIfIsset($arr1, 'foo');
```

Using & before function parameter, tells, that variable will be passed by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 0):

you could consider putting the arrays into a parent array

```
$parent = array(
  'arr_name1' => array(..),
  'arr_name2' => array(..),
);
```

Then you could pass the array name to the function and do `$parent[$arr_name][$field_name]`

Alternatively you could pass the array to the function by reference (prefix the function arg with a `&` ). This will make the changes you make to the `$arr_name` in the function also change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to initialize all used array keys with 0 before incrementing. I do it always simply like that:

```
$arr1 += [$field_name => 0];
```

If $arr1 has key "$field_name" then it will stay untouched, in other way it will be set to 0. Then you can increment it.